# Using global functions in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, function, swiftui, global

I have functions to save, write and delete images from Documents Directory in my app.
I have that functions in every View where I want to use that images.

I've tried to make one file with that functions, I've put it in struct, in class and when I tried to call them, for example `ImageToDirectory.saveImage(image: image, imageName: imageName)` or `ImageToDirectory.getImage(imageName:"Sth")`, Xcode was always telling me that I've been using Unresolved functions.

So my questions is: How can I use functions globally in SwiftUI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like these functions are not static and you need to call them like this (with class initializing):

```
ImageToDirectory().saveImage(image: image, imageName: imageName)
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks! A funny part Is that Xcode still is saying that he doesn't know what function I want to call but I can compile app and It works fine (with errors LOL?)

Comment: Great! Try to clean build folder (Product -> Clean Build Folder), this can probably help with error.